# How to connect AX 2009 with Visual Studio Online (Visual Studio Team Services)

Tags: tfs, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect my AX 2009 installation to VSO (recently renamed to VSTS).

After browsing some forum entries I know that I have to install the following:

- Install Visual Studio 2008 (not the Express Edition)
- Install [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338)
- Install [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986) (This will upgrade both VS2008 and Team Explorer 2008 to SP1)
- Install [VSTS 2008 Forward Compatibility Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10834)

The installation order is important because the SP1 will update VS and Team Explorer, so I followed that order.

Then I created a project in Visual Studio Online.
[image: VSO Project]

Now I want to connect my AX 2009 with the repository in VSO. The VSO is hosting a TFS, so this should work.

---

As far as I could find out to configure the TFS settings you need to set the **Version Control Parameters** and the **System Settings**. I did both as shown in the following screenshots:
[image: Version Control Parameters 1]

[image: Version Control Parameters 2]

[image: System Settings]

When I'm setting the Version Control Paramters the Internet Explorer opened and I needed to authenticate with my User and Password against VSO (so this seems fine to me).

The final step now would be to **Create the Repository** (Tools -> Developer Tools -> Version Control -> Create Repository. But when I try to do this I get the following error-log: *Team Server connection error. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.*
[image: Error Log]

The settings in [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oyDu.png) could be wrong - I'm not really sure what values are to set there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is trying to access a SQL Server database. As VSTS is hosted on Azure and uses multi-tenanting there is no access to SQL server on that URL.

I am pretty sure that this is not ever going to work. VSTS is NOT just hosted TFS and even if it were, Visual Studio 2008 is no longer supported as a client for either TFS or VSTS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be switching to Morphx VCS as it is a system with only three developers working on it. So this should be sufficent and easy to establish.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following components:

- Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 (can be installed side by side with, or as a replacement for VS2008).
- [Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1 Object Model](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdH-MSFT.TeamFoundationServer2010SP1ObjectModelInstaller)
- [KB 2662296](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2662296/fix-an-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-available-to-add-compatibility-support-for-visual-studio-team-foundation-server-2012)
- [KB 2736182](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2736182/a-gdr-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-available-to-add-compatibility-support-for-visual-studio-2012-and-windows-8)

There's additional discussion around this on the [Dynamics Community AX Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/139458).

Comment: In the discussion linked it does not seem as people are getting this to work. Did you manage to get this to work yourself?

Comment: I have used AX2009 with VSTS; though not recently, so can't recall the exact configuration used / find documentation on this...  Will try to run up a copy again sometime soon to document & share in case that's helpful.

Comment: Scanning around I did find a suggestion that for people using VS2008, KB2673642 is needed too: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2673642/a-gdr-update-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1-is-available-to-add-support-for-team-foundation-server-2012-and-team-foundation-service-preview is needed

Comment: A documentation of how it is done, would be extremely helpful. Looking at some discussion I think that I'm not the only one struggling with connecting AX2009 to VSTS.